# Customize Toolbar position of React Quill

Tags: css, reactjs, react-quill

I need to move the Toolbar to the bottom and keep a divider above the toolbar.

Here is what I have tried, yet I have no idea how to place a divider ontop of the toolbar at the bottom of the card.

Also, another issue I noticed in my code is that when I tried the positioning and starts typing, the cursor goes out of the card which is very wrong. I need help to correct that as well.

Below are what I've tried

**index.css**

```
.editor .ql-container {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.editor .ql-toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.editor .ql-snow.ql-toolbar {
    display: block;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

.editor .ql-container.ql-snow {
    border: none;
}

.editor .ql-bubble .ql-editor {
    border: none;
}

.editor .ql-editor {
    min-height: 18em;
    border: none;
}

.editor .toolbar-container {
    position: relative;
}

.toolbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And here is how the above was used in my Compose component
**compose_email.js**

```
import Flex from "components/common/Flex";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import './index.css';
import { Input } from "reactstrap";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import Divider from "components/common/Divider";

export default function ComposeEmail() {

    const [subject, setSubject] = useState("");
    const [body, setBody] = useState("");

    const handleSubjectChange = (event) => {
        setSubject(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleBodyChange = (value) => {
        setBody(value);
    };

    const handleSend = () => {
        setSubject("");
        setBody("");
    };

    const toolbarOptions = {
        container: [
            [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
            [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
            [{ align: [] }],
            ["link", "image", "video"],
            ["clean"],
        ],
        handlers: {},
    };

    return (
        <div style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
            <Card
                elevation={2}
                style={{
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    marginTop: 20,
                    height: '80%',
                    position: 'relative'
                }}>
                <Flex
                    direction={'column'}
                    style={{
                        marginTop: 20,
                        borderRadius: 0
                    }}>
                    <Flex
                        className={'gap-2'}
                        alignItems={'center'}
                        style={{
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            paddingLeft: 16,
                            paddingRight: 16
                        }}
                    >
                        <h5 className="text-600"><strong>Subject</strong></h5>
                        <Input
                            type="text"
                            id="subject"
                            value={subject}
                            placeholder="Your subject"
                            onChange={handleSubjectChange}
                            className="outline-none border-none"
                            style={{
                                outline: 'none',
                                border: 'none',
                                fontWeight: 600,
                                background: 'transparent'
                            }}
                        />
                    </Flex>
                    <Divider />
                    <ReactQuill
                        value={body}
                        onChange={handleBodyChange}
                        modules={{ toolbar: toolbarOptions }}
                        className={'editor'}
                        placeholder="Start typing..."
                    />
                </Flex>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thank you in anticipation of your time.